# PHP variable auto update failure

Tags: variables, refresh

I have this code that I want that `$X` to be updated in the form, so when I press the `+1` button it just keep going adding `1` to the form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>7mada</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  $X =  7 ;?>
<form method="POST" >
    <table border="0" width="60%">
        <tr> <td width ="30%"> Number: </td><td><input type="test"        name="newname" value="<?php echo $X ;?>" readonly></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input name="save" type="submit" value="+1"/>
</form>

<?php
if($_POST){
if($_POST['save'] == "+1"){
$_POST['newname']++;
echo $_POST['newname'];
$X = $_POST['newname'];
}
}else{echo "say smth";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Samy this is the answer for your question :D :D

It completely ignores HTML output, therefore PHP can't interact with events that should be javascript.

you have two options:

1-Do it in Javascript, Live

2-Do it in PHP, requires refresh

If you want to do it in JavaScript, you'd do this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
        <div id="showIt"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(x);</script></div>
    </body>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = 0;
            function add() {
                x++;
                document.getElementById('showIt').innerHTML = x;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

or in PHP:

```html
 <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['x'] = ((isset($_SESSION['x'])) ? $_SESSION['x'] : 0);
        if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        $_SESSION['x']++;
        }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" />
        </form>
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['x'];
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps you,

Mahmoud Elsaadany